# Telling YUI compressor to remove specific non-commented code

Tags: javascript, comments, yui-compressor

In my javascript I have some bits of code specifically used for debugging which I don't want to include in the live site. Is there a way I can semi-comment these bits of code so that they run as javascript normally, but that yui compressor thinks they're comments and removes them?

For example

```
for(key in modules) {
  try { 
     MyApp[key].init(modules[key].params);
  } catch (e) {
     console.log("Module " + key + " threw an error");
     break;
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to comment out the console.log bit automatically when compressing to deploy to the live site. So maybe wrap the code in something like

```
   //yuiIgnore
         console.log("Module " + key + " threw an error");
   //endyuiIgnore
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the code you're trying to minify BUT is not getting stripped out. Secondly, can you please provide the command line you run to minify or the configuration settings (if you're using the .NET port).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With regard specifically to `console.log` statements:

I'm using `sed` to replace `"console"` with `"//console"` before launching the compressor:

```
sed -e "s/console/\/\/console/g" originalWithConsoleStatements.js > noConsoleStatements.js
```

This statement sits inside a shell script which then launches the compressor.

Comment: This assumes all console.log statements is on one line, otherwise you'll get syntax errors, I'd think...

Comment: this is a great idea!